# Partition function in quicksort not working correctly

Tags: sorting, computer-science, quicksort

I am trying to use the partition function of quicksort to divide the array between 2 parts one less than the desired element (pivot)and other greater than the desired element(pivot).

**Partition Function**

```
void partition(int a[],int beg,int end,int pivotindex){
    swap(a[pivotindex],a[end]);
    int x=a[end];
    int i=beg-1;

    for(int j=beg;j<=end-1;j++){
        if(a[j]<=x){
           i++;
           swap(a[i],a[j]);
        }
    }

    swap(a[i+1],a[end]);
    return ;
}
```

**Input**

```
0 1 2 0 2 1 1 //array elements
2 //pivot index
```

**Output**

```
0 1 1 0 2 1 2
```

On dry running the code, the output is correct but as the text books have specified the role of partition function, I was expecting this output

```
0 1 1 0 1 2 2
```

or some other combination of it, but both "2 s" have to be at the end of it.
Is there a flaw in my understanding of partition function or is there a problem with my implementation?